# No me funciona la sobreescritura no pasa a la funcion de la clase hija

Tags: java

Voy a intentar ser lo mas escueto posible e ir al grano.
Tengo una superClase llamada Equipos: En la cual le he añadido un array de Luchadores y luego lo he enlazado mediante una funcion.

```
private String nombreDios;
private String universo;
private Luchadores luc[];
 //Constructor
public Equipos(String n,String u){
    this.nombreDios=n;
    this.universo=u;

}


public void asignarLuchadores(Luchadores uno,Luchadores dos,Luchadores tres){
    luc=new Luchadores[3];
    luc[0]=uno;
    luc[1]=uno;
    luc[2]=dos;
}
```

Bien el problema radica en esta funcion necesito que llame a la funcion de clase hija 
   public void  tiradaAleatoriaAtaque(Equipos f){

```
    }
```

La clase hija es Luchadores

```
public  class Luchadores extends Equipos {
private int ptosVida;
private int ptosResistencia;
private int ptsAtaqueFisico;
private String nombre;


@Override
 public void  tiradaAleatoriaAtaque(Equipos f){

   super.tiradaAleatoriaAtaque(f);
     System.out.println("hola");//Lo hice para ver si pasaba por aqui pero no



  }
```

No me pasa por esta funcion.

Tambien tengo otra clase hija de luchador llamada Saiyajin el cual quiero que haga la funcion completa

```
   public class Saiyajin extends Luchadores {
private int ptosAtaqueKi;
private String [] estados;
private String estadoActual;



@Override
  public void  tiradaAleatoriaAtaque(Equipos f){
   super.tiradaAleatoriaAtaque(f);
   System.out.println("ok");
   Random r=new Random();
   int suma=this.getPtosAtaqueKi()+this.getPtsAtaqueFisico();
   if (this.getUniverso()=="Universo 7") {
       if (this.getPtosVida()>=(super.getPtosVida()*80/100)) {
      this.estadoActual= this.estados[0];
      suma=suma*1;
       }else if(this.getPtosVida()>=(super.getPtosVida()*60/100)&&this.getPtosVida()<(super.getPtosVida()*80/100)){
            this.estadoActual= this.estados[1];
            suma=suma*2;
       }else if (this.getPtosVida()>=(super.getPtosVida()*40/100)&&super.getPtosVida()<(super.getPtosVida()*60/100)){
           this.estadoActual=this.estados[2];
           suma=suma*4;
       }else if(this.getPtosVida()>=(super.getPtosVida()*20/100)&&super.getPtosVida()<(super.getPtosVida()*40/100)){
           this.estadoActual=this.estados[3];
           suma=suma*20;
       }else if(this.getPtosVida()<(super.getPtosVida()*20/100)){
           this.estadoActual=this.estados[4];
           suma=suma*100;
       }
   }
   if (this.getUniverso()=="Universo 6") {
           if (this.getPtosVida()>=(super.getPtosVida()*70/100)) {
      this.estadoActual= this.estados[0];
      suma=suma*1;
       }else if(this.getPtosVida()>=(super.getPtosVida()*40/100)&&this.getPtosVida()<(super.getPtosVida()*70/100)){
            this.estadoActual= this.estados[1];
            suma=suma*2;
       }else if (this.getPtosVida()<(super.getPtosVida()*40/100)){
           this.estadoActual=this.estados[2];
           suma=suma*4;
       }

        /*   if () { TO DO FALTA POR ARREGLAR PUNTOS DE VIDA
               System.out.println("Ha muerto el");
       }else{
                   int ataqueTotal=r.nextInt(0+suma);
     f.setPtosVida(ataqueTotal);
           }*/


   }



  }
```

No consigo hacer que funcione la sobreescritura al llamar en el main 
    universo7.asignarLuchadores(goku,vegueta,piccolo);
   universo7.tiradaAleatoriaAtaque(universo7.buscarLuchador(numero));

No pasa por las demas funciones solo hace la del padre cuando todos son luchadores y dos de ellos saiyajines estoy usando el array del equipo

Comment: Tienes errores conceptuales muy graves en tu modelo de datos. La clase `Luchadores` no debería extender de  `Equipos`, son dos entidades totalmente distintas. Además poner los nombres de las clases en plural no te ayuda a entender lo que pretende la POO. Por poner un ejemplo, `Luchador` extendería de `Persona`, porque un `Luchador` **puede ser una `Persona`**, pero ¿puede un `Luchador` **ser un `Equipo`**? No. Puede ser parte de un `Equipo`, pero no es un `Equipo`. Entender eso es fundamental, sino estarás perdido totalmente en tu diseño. Creo que ya te comenté algo sobre eso antes.

Comment: @A.Cedano *La clase Luchadores no debería extender de Equipos, son dos entidades totalmente distintas...* Eso depende de la interpretación que le des. Imagínate que esté creando un gamemode en [SA-MP](https://www.sa-mp.com/) y su GM esté compuesto por dos equipos: `Red` y `Blue`. En este caso, tomamos `Red` y `Blue` como "equipos", no como "colores". Por lo tanto, `Red` si puede ser un equipo, siempre y cuando, nos estemos refiriendo a dicho contexto (es decir, al gamemode).

Comment: Cree la clase luchador porque luego estan las clases hijas de luchadores que son sayajin, demonioDelFrio etc.   Es decir luchador funciona como persona. Entonces Luchador no debería de extender de equipo? De todas formas no entiendo porque no me hace la función de sobre escritura que hice.      Gracias por todo:)

Comment: Haciendo la clase Luchador sin que sea el padre Equipos he tenido un problema en la clase hija Saiyajin en el ultimo codigo de tirada aleatoria necesito saber que universo es para poder cambiar uno de sus atribuyos y el universo esta en Equipos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo entendí tu clase `Equipos` como un equipo de competidores en un combate o evento, algo así como un equipo de fútbol, un equipo de lucha, un equipo de tenis, etc. Si no es ese el contexto, y `Equipo` se refiere a algo así como una consola de juego, es evidente que el enfoque debería cambiar (teniendo en cuenta el comentario de @MrDave1999).

Si la clase es un grupo de competidores, la aproximación acorde con los principios de la POO sería esta.

Antes de presentar las clases, quiero hacer notar que la *convención de nombre* es importante. Generalmente las clases se llaman en **singular**, porque **representan entidades únicas**. Es un concepto que parece banal, pero que ayuda mucho a entender la POO. Es decir, una clase es como un molde para crear objetos de ese tipo. Cuando creas una instancia de `Equipo` o de `Luchador` no creas **varios** equipos o varios luchadores, creas **un solo** equipo o un solo luchador.

El modelo que te propongo es este. Es un modelo mínimo, faltan métodos que luego puedes incorporar, he puesto lo esencial sólo para mostrar cómo funciona.

### Clase `Equipo`

```
class Equipo 
{

    private String nombreDios;
    private String universo;
    private List<Luchador> lstLuchadores;

    public Equipo(String n,String u)
    {
        this.nombreDios=n;
        this.universo=u;
    }
    public String getUniverso()
    {
        return this.universo;
    }
    public void setLuchadores(List<Luchador> lstLuchadores){
        this.lstLuchadores=lstLuchadores;
    }
}
```

---

### Clase `Luchador`

Nótese que esta clase no extiende de `Equipo`. En la lógica del `main` veremos cómo desde la lista que contiene a los luchadores podemos obtener los datos de la clase `Equipo` que necesitemos.

```
class Luchador 
{
    protected int ptosVida;
    protected int ptosResistencia;
    protected int ptsAtaqueFisico;
    protected String nombre;

    public Luchador(String nombre, int ptosVida, int ptosResistencia, int ptsAtaqueFisico)
    {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.ptosVida=ptosVida;
        this.ptosResistencia=ptosResistencia;
        this.ptsAtaqueFisico=ptsAtaqueFisico;        
    }
    
    public String getNombre ()
    {
        return this.nombre;
    }
    
    public int getPtosVida ()
    {
        return this.ptosVida;
    }
    
    public int getPtosResistencia ()
    {
        return this.ptosResistencia;
    }        

    public int getPtosAtaqueFisico ()
    {
        return this.ptsAtaqueFisico;
    }    
    /*
        OJO a este método
        En tu código lanzabas la suma de puntos en
        el escenario de ataque si necesidad
    */
    public int getTotalPuntos ()
    {
        return (this.ptosVida)+(this.ptosResistencia)+(this.ptsAtaqueFisico);
    }        

    /*
        Pongo sólo un setter de prueba
    */    

    public void cambiarPtosVida (int ptosValue)
    {
        /*
            Imaginemos aquí una lógica para verificar
            si se le da Game Over por ejemplo
            ...Solamente restamos, por brevedad
        */
        this.ptosVida=this.ptosVida+(ptosValue);
    }
        
    public String toString ()
    {
        return String.format("Nombre: %s %n Puntos: %d  <v: %d r: %d a: %d>",
                              nombre, getTotalPuntos(), ptosVida, ptosResistencia, ptsAtaqueFisico);
    }          
}
```

---

### Clase `Saiyajin`

```
class Saiyajin extends Luchador 
{
    /*
        Este campo sería una PROPIEDAD que tiene un Saiyajin
        y que no tiene la clase padre Luchador
    */
    private String propioDeSaiyajin;
    private int ptosAtaqueKi;
    
    public Saiyajin(String nombre, int ptosVida, int ptosResistencia, int ptsAtaqueFisico, int ptosAtaqueKi)
    {
        /*
            Llamamos a super y le pasamos los campos
            que tiene en común con el hijo
        */
        super(nombre, ptosVida, ptosResistencia, ptsAtaqueFisico);
        this.ptosAtaqueKi=ptosAtaqueKi;
    }
    
    public int getPtosAtaqueKi()
    {
        return this.ptosAtaqueKi;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getTotalPuntos ()
    {
        return (super.getTotalPuntos())+(this.ptosAtaqueKi);
    } 
    
    @Override
    public void cambiarPtosVida (int ptosValue)
    {
        /*
            Imaginemos aquí una lógica para verificar
            si se le da Game Over por ejemplo
            ...Solamente restamos, por brevedad
        */
        ptosVida=ptosVida+(ptosValue);
    }    
    
    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return String.format("Nombre: %s %n Puntos: %d  <v: %d r: %d a: %d k: %d>",nombre,getTotalPuntos(),
                             ptosVida, ptosResistencia, ptsAtaqueFisico,ptosAtaqueKi);
    }  
}
```

---

### Prueba en cualquier contexto

Teniendo el modelo de datos montado de ese modo, vamos a lanzar una prueba. Aquí la clase se llama `Rextester` porque el fiddle exige que se llame así. Esta podría ser tu clase principal u otra.

Lo que se hace aquí es:

- Manejar dos objetos de la clase `Equipo`
- Manejar dos listas de objetos de la clase `Luchador`. Esas listas se llenarán con objetos de la clase `Luchador` o de la clase `Saiyajin` según sea necesario
- Se simularán dos combates tomando jugadores aleatorios entre ambas listas. Es interesante pensar aquí en una clase `Combate` que defina todas las reglas sobre los combates, etc. Si esta clase existiera, toda la lógica implementada en los métodos `combatOne()` y `combatTwo()` iría allí y no en la clase principal. Pero eso ya te corresponde a ti, refinar el modelo, una vez hayas entendido el *quid*  del asunto.

Nada más, todo está más o menos explicado en el código. Obsérvalo y analízalo, para que veas cómo se obtiene la información de cada objeto de forma transparente y sin complicaciones ni código spaguetti.

```
class Rextester
{  
    private static List <Luchador> luchadoresEqOne;
    private static List <Luchador> luchadoresEqTwo;
    private static Equipo eqOne;
    private static Equipo eqTwo;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /*Equipo 1*/
        eqOne=new Equipo("Equipo1","Universo1");
        /*Lista de luchadores*/
        luchadoresEqOne=new ArrayList<Luchador>();
        /*Asignamos cada luchador*/
        luchadoresEqOne.add(new Luchador ("LowMan-E1",1,2,3));
        luchadoresEqOne.add(new Luchador ("HitMan-E1",10,20,30));
        luchadoresEqOne.add(new Saiyajin ("Chino-E1",10,20,30,40));
        /*Mediante el setter de Equipo asignamos la lista de luchadores*/
        eqOne.setLuchadores(luchadoresEqOne);

        /*Eqipo 2: hacemos lo mismo que con el Equipo 1*/
        eqTwo=new Equipo("Equipo2","Universo2");
        luchadoresEqTwo=new ArrayList<Luchador>();
        luchadoresEqTwo.add(new Luchador ("Batman-E2",20,30,40));
        luchadoresEqTwo.add(new Saiyajin ("Nokko-E2",30,20,20,60));
        luchadoresEqTwo.add(new Saiyajin ("Gokuuu-E2",1,50,2,90));

        eqTwo.setLuchadores(luchadoresEqTwo);

        /*
            Lanzamos dos combates seguidos de prueba
            convendría tener una clase Combate que 
            para lanzar combartes y establecer las reglas
        */
        combatOne();
        combatTwo();
    }
    
    private static void combatOne()
    {
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        Luchador randomOne = luchadoresEqOne.get(randomizer.nextInt(luchadoresEqOne.size()));
        Luchador randomTwo = luchadoresEqTwo.get(randomizer.nextInt(luchadoresEqTwo.size()));
        randomizer=null;
        /* 
            En todo este bloque podrás comprobar cómo se obtiene datos
            sea de la clase Equipo, sea de la clase Luchador
            sea de la clase Sayayyin, según sea el objeto
        */
        System.out.format("------------------------------------------------------------%n%n");   
        System.out.format("COMBATE 1: %s (%s) vs %s (%s) %nAntes del enfrentamiento:%n%n",
                          randomOne.getNombre(),eqOne.getUniverso(),randomTwo.getNombre(),eqTwo.getUniverso());   

        /*
            Obsérvese la utilidad del método toString
        */
        
        System.out.println(randomOne.toString());   
        System.out.println(randomTwo.toString());
        /*
            Un cálculo simple aquí sólo para demostración de los métodos
        */
        System.out.format("%nDespués del enfrentamiento:");   
        if(randomOne.getPtosResistencia() > randomTwo.getPtosAtaqueFisico())
        {
            System.out.format("%n%s perderá 4 puntos y %s ganará 1 punto%n%n",randomOne.getNombre(),randomTwo.getNombre());   
            randomOne.cambiarPtosVida(-4);
            randomTwo.cambiarPtosVida(1);           
        }else{
             System.out.format("%n%s ganará 3 puntos y %s perderá 5 puntos%n%n",randomOne.getNombre(),randomTwo.getNombre());   
             randomOne.cambiarPtosVida(3);
             randomTwo.cambiarPtosVida(-5); 
            
        }
        System.out.println(randomOne.toString());   
        System.out.println(randomTwo.toString());  
        System.out.format("------------------------------------------------------------%n%n");          
    }
    
    
    private static void combatTwo()
    {
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        Luchador randomOne = luchadoresEqOne.get(randomizer.nextInt(luchadoresEqOne.size()));
        Luchador randomTwo = luchadoresEqTwo.get(randomizer.nextInt(luchadoresEqTwo.size()));
        randomizer=null;
        
        System.out.format("COMBATE 2: %s (%s) vs %s (%s) %nAntes del enfrentamiento:%n%n",
                          randomOne.getNombre(),eqOne.getUniverso(),randomTwo.getNombre(),eqTwo.getUniverso());   

        /*
            Obsérvese la utilidad del método toString
        */
        
        System.out.println(randomOne.toString());   
        System.out.println(randomTwo.toString());
        /*
            Un cálculo simple aquí sólo para demostración de los métodos
        */
        System.out.format("%nDespués del enfrentamiento:");   
        if(randomOne.getPtosResistencia() > randomTwo.getPtosAtaqueFisico())
        {
            System.out.format("%n%s perderá 2 puntos y %s ganará 2 punto%n%n",randomOne.getNombre(),randomTwo.getNombre());   
            randomOne.cambiarPtosVida(-2);
            randomTwo.cambiarPtosVida(2);           
        }else{
             System.out.format("%n%s ganará 0 puntos y %s perderá 2 puntos%n%n",randomOne.getNombre(),randomTwo.getNombre());   
             //randomOne.cambiarPtosVida(3); No se modifica porque no ganará ni perderá puntos
             randomTwo.cambiarPtosVida(-2); 
            
        }
        System.out.println(randomOne.toString());   
        System.out.println(randomTwo.toString());  
        System.out.format("------------------------------------------------------------%n%n");          
    }
}
```

---

**Salida:**

La salida de este código sería algo como esto. Dado que es aleatorio, podría variar en cada prueba:

```
------------------------------------------------------------

COMBATE 1: HitMan-E1 (Universo1) vs Gokuuu-E2 (Universo2) 
Antes del enfrentamiento:

Nombre: HitMan-E1 
 Puntos: 60  <v: 10 r: 20 a: 30>
Nombre: Gokuuu-E2 
 Puntos: 143  <v: 1 r: 50 a: 2 k: 90>

Después del enfrentamiento:
HitMan-E1 perderá 4 puntos y Gokuuu-E2 ganará 1 punto

Nombre: HitMan-E1 
 Puntos: 56  <v: 6 r: 20 a: 30>
Nombre: Gokuuu-E2 
 Puntos: 144  <v: 2 r: 50 a: 2 k: 90>
------------------------------------------------------------

COMBATE 2: LowMan-E1 (Universo1) vs Batman-E2 (Universo2) 
Antes del enfrentamiento:

Nombre: LowMan-E1 
 Puntos: 6  <v: 1 r: 2 a: 3>
Nombre: Batman-E2 
 Puntos: 90  <v: 20 r: 30 a: 40>

Después del enfrentamiento:
LowMan-E1 ganará 0 puntos y Batman-E2 perderá 2 puntos

Nombre: LowMan-E1 
 Puntos: 6  <v: 1 r: 2 a: 3>
Nombre: Batman-E2 
 Puntos: 88  <v: 18 r: 30 a: 40>
------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

### Demo

<kbd>[**`VER DEMOSTRACIÓN ONLINE`**](https://rextester.com/GLH13669)</kbd>

---

### PD

Este modelo es sólo para que tengas una idea, no es que tenga que ser exactamente así, algunas cosas pueden variar según el contexto. En las clases faltan métodos, he puesto sólo lo básico por motivos de brevedad.

Comment: Gracias por todo maestro!!!

mas o menos he entendido el codigo solo que colecciones aún no he hecho mucho pero me ha servido para entender mejor el poo en java!

Comment: @GolpeCelestial me alegro de que te haya ayudado. La clave aquí, sobre todo con el problema que tenías para recuperar datos de `Equipo` es que por ejemplo `eqOne` es una instancia de `Equipo`, y a esa instancia le hemos seteado una lista de objetos de la clase `List <Luchador> luchadoresEqOne`. Pues bien, como se ve en los métodos de combate, si quieres sacar algo de `Equipo` usas `eqOne` y si quieres algo de `Luchador` usas el elemento de dentro de la lista.